# Bitbucket pipelines: The type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: .net-core, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm hoping someone can help me out. Thanks!

I'm trying to deploy my dotnet core 2.0 API

When I try and build the project with bitbucket pipelines I get multiple errors finding references. It does restore the project successfully.

However the project builds successfully on my laptop.

folder structure:

```
/API
  /Controllers
  /Migrations
  /Models
  /Services
  API.csproj
  Program.cs
  Startup.cs
```

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        image: microsoft/dotnet
        name: Check if it builds
        script:
          - cd API
          - dotnet build
```

example error:

```
Services/MyService.cs(18,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IRepository<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/API/API.csproj]
```

---

**Note** I have the latest version of dotnet, same as I'm using in bitbucket pipelines. I have checked via running `dotnet --info`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i've figured out what was the cause of this issue. I feel really silly for not figuring this out sooner.

My git repository was somehow setup with ignorecase = true. 
I have switched it to false (which will prevent this issue in the future).

This means that I can have two of the same files or folders.

I had renamed a folder to a different case. 
My repo had

```
API/
  API.csproj
```

and

```
api/
  api.csproj
```

My Mac couldn't allow for both so I only saw one folder and one project on my local machine.

To fix this, I had to `git rm -r --cached api`

This deleted the duplicate folder

I had the project file as a duplicate as well so used `git rm -f api.csproj` to remove the file from the repository.

Then `git pull` to bring those changes into my local master branch.

Comment: thanks. FYI: this is the only answer exists in the internet for this problem.